# TeamCity + git and authentication for submodules

Tags: git, teamcity, git-submodules

Trying to configure TeamCity to build our project, I'm having trouble getting the git VCS module to checkout a submodule. The submodule should be checked out using the same authentication as the root module, but I cannot figure out how to configure TeamCity for this. I have tried both password and private key authentication, but they both fail:

```
[12:07:14]: Patch is broken, can be found in file: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\cache\temp8149231956777659708patch_48
[12:07:14]: RunBuildException when running build stage UpdateSourcesFromServer: Failed to build patch for build 31 {build id=48}, VCS root: ssh://host/repo#master {id=2}, due to error: Patch building failed: 
jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.submodules.SubmoduleFetchException: Cannot fetch submodule. Repository URL: 'ssh://*****@host/repo', submodule path: 'subrepo'.
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: ssh://*****@host/subrepo: Auth fail
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
```

TeamCity runs on a windows machine and the git repos are on a linux machine.

Is it possible to configure authentication for submodules in TeamCity, or can anyone come up with a good workaround?

Comment: Can you first configure TeamCity (in another config) to check out directly the submodule (as an independent repo)?

Comment: I could, but I don't want it to checkout HEAD, but instead the revision that is referenced by the main module...

Comment: Currently seeing the same issue in my project, using Teamcity 2023.11 

```
Failed to perform checkout on agent: Submodules checkout failed: /usr/bin/git -c core.askpass=/opt/buildagent/temp/buildTmp/pass4093930138785685726 -c credential.helper= fetch --progress --recurse-submodules=no origin +refs/*:refs/* command failed.
  exit code: 128
```
Doesn't seem to be as resolved as hoped...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have been an issue with TeamCity 5. I now have upgraded to TeamCity 6 and the project checks out fine.